# UICollectionView is extremely laggy when I scroll up or down

Tags: ios, swift, lag

I'm using Alamofire to fetch JSON data from the YTS api and load them on a collection view cell. It's basically an app that provides info about upcoming movies and recently added. Here's how I'm using Alamofire.

```
func getMovieData(movieData: Data) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        do {
            var movieJSONData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: movieData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStand
            /*var name: String!
            var desc: String!
            var genre: [String]!*/
            if let data = movieJSONData["data"] as? JSONStand {
                if let movies = data["movies"] as! [JSONStand]! {
                    for i in 0..<movies.count {
                        let item = movies[i]
                        let movieName = item["title_english"] as! String
                        let movieDescription = item["synopsis"] as! String
                        let movieGenre = item["genres"] as! [String]
                        let movieYear = item["year"] as! Int
                        let movieRating = item["rating"] as! Double
                        let movieYoutubeTrailerCode = item["yt_trailer_code"] as! String
                        let movieRuntime = item["runtime"] as! Int
                        if let movieImage = item["medium_cover_image"] as? String {
                            let movieImageURL = URL(string: movieImage)
                            let movieImageData = NSData(contentsOf: movieImageURL!)
                            if movieImageData != nil {
                                self.mainMovieImage = UIImage(data: movieImageData as! Data)
                            }
                            else {
                                print("No image found")
                            }

                            if let torrents = item["torrents"] as? [JSONStand] {
                                for i in 0..<torrents.count {
                                    let item = torrents[i]
                                    let movieSize = item["size"] as! String
                                    if movieSize.isEmpty == false {
                                        self.movieSizeLabel = movieSize
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        print("Couldn't get size")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.movie.append(Movie.init(names: movieName, descriptions: movieDescription, images: self.mainMovieImage, genres: movieGenre, years: movieYear, ratings: movieRating, sizes: self.movieSizeLabel, ytcodes: movieYoutubeTrailerCode, runtimes: movieRuntime))
                             self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            var errorStringValue = error.localizedDescription
            if error.localizedDescription.contains("correct") {
                errorStringValue = "Internet connection unavailable, please connect to a wifi."
            }
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: errorStringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

}
```

Also here's how I'm loading them on the cells.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cellImageView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    cellMovieLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    movieLoadingIndicator = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIActivityIndicatorView
    cellImageView.image = movie[indexPath.row].images
    cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cellMovieLabel.text = movie[indexPath.row].names
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What does the time profiler in instruments tell you. You may find one of the calls in `cellForItemAt indexPath` is gobbling a lot of CPU. Are your images much larger than they need to be?. Also calling `reloadData` on every single new data point is expensive. It might be better to call it just once at the end of parsing all the data.

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure what time profiler is. also the images are 230 by 345.

Comment: @safasfmasklfalskf `self.movie.append(Movie.init(names: movieName, descriptions: movieDescription, images: self.mainMovieImage, genres: movieGenre, years: movieYear, ratings: movieRating, sizes: self.movieSizeLabel, ytcodes: movieYoutubeTrailerCode, runtimes: movieRuntime))` - In this line, you are initializing `Movie` object on main thread right. Does it involve some operations inside

Comment: If so, please move it outside main thread

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri Hi thank you, that helped a lot but now I'm getting the same movie but three times. So there are three cells with that same movie, for every single movie.

Comment: @safasfmasklfalskf, check the content of the array once by using breakpoints

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri can the for loop cause this?

Comment: No. Before moving this out of mainthread, were you getting the same issue?

Comment: Nope. But what I did was create the variables before the viewDidLoad and fixed the issue but the lag is still there :/

Comment: so, since the lag is not resolved after moving that particular line out of main thread. I believe it's something else causing the problem. Please check your custom UICollectionViewCell code once

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri the problem was that I was creating a custom flow layout, I removed it and it's now perfect. Not sure why it was causing it.

Comment: I faced a similar situation. It happened due to my autolayout constraints getting set for each cell. Anyway, good luck for your project

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri thanks so much for your help :D